# How to regenerate ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig?

Tags: flutter, xcode, pubspec

Currently I am changing the app version directly in info.ptlist instead of referring the version details from pubspec.yml. Seems the variables used in info.ptlist directly referring from ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig but I couldn't find a way to regenerate it. Please somebody help me.

I have no way to regenerate the Generated.xcconfig

Comment: When you run the flutter build ios command or trigger a build from an (IDE) like Android Studio or Visual Studio Code, Flutter analyzes your project's configuration and generates the Generated.xcconfig file based on that analysis.

Comment: i will update as answer please upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generated.xcconfig is auto generated, just change the version in pubspec.yml and execute the "flutter run" command , it will automatically regenerate the Generated.xcconfig file. You don't need to edit it manually.

Answer (score 3):

When you run the flutter build ios command or trigger a build from an (IDE) like Android Studio or Visual Studio Code, Flutter analyzes your project's configuration and generates the Generated.xcconfig file based on that analysis.